# SQL for setting column value same as next row's column value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this

```
--------------------------
id    some_column
--------------------------
1      null
2      abc
3      null
4      null
5      def
6      ghi
```

In my scenario, some initial rows in the table have null in some_column. **All the latest rows have some_column value properly set**.

I want to run a query which can replace all the null values of some_column by copying value from next not null value.

For example, after running the query, table will become

```
--------------------------
id    some_column
--------------------------
1      abc
2      abc
3      def
4      def
5      def
6      ghi
```

I was trying something like this

```
update table as t1 set some_column = (select some_column from table as t2 where t2.id > t1.id and t2.some_column is not null limit 1) where some_column is null
```

but getting error

```
You can't specify target table 't1' for update in FROM clause
```

Comment: You need to define what you mean by "next row".  SQL has no built-in nor default concept of order within tables.

Comment: @RBarryYoung If you look at his attempted query, he means the next highest `id` with a non-null value.

Comment: @RBarryYoung my definition of next row is `where id > current row and some_column is not null`

Comment: @RBarryYoung is correct.  You would need to pull your data first, then identify what you need to update manually.  There really is no automatic way to do this reliably.

Comment: @durbnpoisn Sure there is, with a JOIN. Wait for my answer.

Comment: As far as I can remember you can't use the same table (alias?) for the actual UPDATE together with a/the SELECT inside the subquery of your UPDATE, I think this has todo with the locking mechanism.

Comment: @Barmar  many years (decades, really) of answering similar questions has taught me not to assume that, but rather, like SQL, to insist on an explicit expression of order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a `JOIN`:

```
UPDATE t AS t0
JOIN (
    SELECT t1.id, MIN(t2.id) new_id
    FROM t AS t1
    JOIN t AS t2 ON t1.id < t2.id
    WHERE t1.some_column IS NULL
    AND t2.some_column IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY t1.id) AS tnew ON t0.id = tnew.id
JOIN t AS t3 ON t3.id = tnew.new_id
SET t0.some_column = t3.some_column
```

The `tnew` subquery matches up each ID with a null value with the next highest ID with a non-null value. I then join this twice with the original table, to pair up the row to be updated with 
the value from the row with the replacement value.

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7f747/1)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a correlated subquery with order by and limit to get the first not null value after a null value see select [**demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/617973/1) for a correlated subquery,below query will update the null values of column with the next not null value

```
update t 
join(
select t1.*,
(select some_column 
 from t where id > t1.id 
 and some_column is not null
order by id limit 1
) newname
from t t1
  ) t2
on t.id = t2.id 
set t.some_column =t2.newname
where t.some_column is null
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a0ab38/2)