# Calculate difference between two rows of the same type

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose I have the following table (see below), and I want to find the entries where the "memsize" or "totalstorage" for the same machine (= same vmnaam value) has changed.

```
ID  VMNaam  Memsize totalstorage dataentrytime
1      x      12         150         blabla
2      x      12         150         blabla
3      x      14         150         blabla
4      Y      12         150         blabla
5      Y      20         150         blabla
6      Y      18         150         blabla
```

The following query finds those rows

```
 SELECT    realTable.VMnaam,
            realTable.memsize,
            realTable.totalstorage

    FROM      vmresourcetest realTable
              LEFT OUTER JOIN (
                 SELECT   (ID+1) AS 'virtualId',
                          (ID) AS 'realId',
                          vmnaam AS 'vmnaamVirtual',
                          memsize AS 'virtualMemsize',
                          totalstorage AS 'virtualTotalstorage'
                 FROM     vmresourcetest
                 ORDER BY vmnaam
              ) virtual 
              ON virtual.virtualId = realTable.id and virtual.vmnaamVirtual = realTable.vmnaam
    where IFNULL((realTable.memsize - virtual.virtualMemsize), 0) <> 0 or IFNULL((realTable.totalstorage - virtual.virtualTotalstorage), 0) <> 0
```

However, when the machine rows are scrambled, my query obviously doesn't work anymore because the ID of the previous machine entry might be the ID of another machine

E.g

```
1 x blablabla
2 y blablalba
3 y blablabll
4 x blablbla
```

I somehow want to change ID+1 into (select id from realtable where id > id), but that doesn't work. 
Any ideas on how to fix my problem?

Comment: Take a look at the answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25790710/sql-for-setting-column-value-same-as-next-rows-column-value/25791083#25791083 The question isn't exactly the same, but I think the general approach should help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you going:

```
SELECT curr.VMnaam,
       curr.memsize,
       curr.totalstorage

FROM   vmresourcetest curr LEFT JOIN   
       vmresourcetest nxt ON curr.id < nxt.id 
                    AND curr.vmnaam = curr.vmnaam
                    AND (curr.memsize != nxt.memsize 
                           OR curr.totalstorage != nxt.totalstorage)
AND NOT EXISTS ( -- there is no record between current and next record
         SELECT * 
         FROM vmresourcetest  
         WHERE id > curr.id AND id < nxt.id AND vmnaam = curr.vmnaam)
```